# Cloudformation Parameter to connect fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm setting up a CloudFormation for a load balancing ECS that will be connected to a Fargate container. How do I make a Parameter in Fargate to be able to choose from my existing Fargate Images.

Using this template.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html
Currently, it uses Ec2 but I want to use Fargate.

```
  containerDefinitions:
      - name: '${Environment}-{Name}'
        logConfiguration:
          logDriver: awslogs
          options:
            awslogs-group: "$/ecs/{Environment}-{Name}"
            awslogs-region: eu-west-1
            awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
        portMappings:
        - hostPort: 3000
          protocol: tcp
          containerPort: 3000
        cpu: 256
        memory: 1024
        image:
```

I need to assign image based on a parameter

```
Parameters:
  Name:
    Type: String
    Description: Name the application.
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment of the application.
    AllowedValues:
        - prod
        - stage
        - dev
```

Here I need to add a dropdown menu to choose the Fargate I want, or maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: Can you show your current template and show what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Added which template i started with, currently I have some issues in the yaml. I will add the part of the taskdefinitioni have problem with

Comment: Its easy to just set up everything in the console but want to have this in CloudFormation.
Maybe I need to add the image as a string of the image. But I would like it to find current repos that exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I would like it to find current repos that exist.

Sadly, **that's not possible**. CFN simply does not have such functionality. For some resources you can do that using [AWS-specific parameter types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types), but ECR images are not one of those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I overthought the CFN. I can use the ECR created and the used Environment variable to get prod, stage, or dev environment but they are still in the same repo. Thanks for the link that will be helpful

Comment: @MarcusLagerstedt No problem. If you have per-defined set of images, you can hard-code them, and you will have a list from which a user can choose the image he/she wants.